# Fullcalender V5 How to get ResourceId of events

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using Fullcalender scheduler V5. How shall I get the resourceId on eventDrop,eventClick etc. I tried like this:

```
 eventResize:function(info)
    {
        alert(info.event.resourceId);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.

```
eventResize: function(info) {
alert("Resource: " + info.event._def.resourceIds);
}
```

It was here. Didn't spot this link until now.

[ResourceId of events in FullcalenderV5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59644244/how-to-get-resource-id-on-eventreceive-in-resourcetimegridday-in-fullcalendar)